# Get product - checkout/item price with product tax class ( Ignoring customer address tax )

Tags: magento-1.9, tax

I'm displaying the catalog prices with tax. Everything works great. Although i have setup different tax zones. Ex. outside EU 0 %.
When a user logins in and sets up an address outside EU i don't want the catalog price to change to the one with 0%. I want it to remain with the default tax class and recalculate it upon checkout.

Say we have a product with 24% tax class valued at 50$.
I want to continue showing 50$ until checkout where it'll include the tax zones checks and remove the tax due to the customer's address being outside EU.

Say in cart i can get the items price with

```
$this->helper('checkout')->getPriceInclTax($_item);
```

And the grand total

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$totals = $quote->getTotals();
$grandtotal = $totals["grand_total"]->getValue();
```

Any way i can get the grand total and the item price with Tax but strict keep the default tax class id that the product has ? And not get overriden by the customer tax class due to another tax zone ?

Thanks